# How to programmatically change theme in OctoberCMS?

Tags: php, themes, theming, octobercms

I can change the active theme from the management dashboard in OctoberCMS by going to Settings/Front-end theme. Now I want to give the end-users the ability to change the theme by clicking on an icon. How can I change the theme programatically on the server side? I could not find the relevant code in the documents.

Comment: Would you like to allow each end-user to choose their own theme (user after logging in sees chosen theme, not the default one). Or just allow user to change the global theme?

Comment: @rsobon I want to let them choose their own theme.

Answer (score 3):

CLI command of enabling some theme is:

```
php artisan theme:use rainlab-vanilla
```

It means that you can call php code something like that:

```
Artisan::call('theme:use', ['rainlab-vanilla'])
```